# How To Work With SQL Database Added As Item In Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, ado.net

If I'm letting Visual Studio take care of adding an SQL Server database to an existing project, it adds the connection string to app.config. How can I use use THAT connection string to make my own connections and datasets?

Comment: I recommend you to use Linq to SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, both of those helped get me on the right track. I found this quite simple, yet highly annoying. The solution I used was:

1. using System.Configuration;
2. add a reference System.configuration
3. create a new connection with SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionFromApp.Config"].ConnectionString)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` to read the connection string when required.

For example, if you opening a SQL Connection, use the assign the "Connection String" property to the value retrieved from `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ("MyConnectionString")`

If it is placed in the appropriate section in the app config file, then you can use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` to retrieve it as well.

Read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Place the connection string in your app.config then use

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[str].ConnectionString.ToString();

to get the connection string.

For example:

```
private string GetConnectionString(string str)
    {
        //variable to hold our return value
        string conn = string.Empty;
        //check if a value was provided
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            //name provided so search for that connection
            conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[str].ConnectionString.ToString();
        }
        else
        //name not provided, get the 'default' connection
        {
            conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnStr].ConnectionString;
        }
        //return the value
        return conn;
    }
```

Then you can reference the connection using ado.net or Linq

For Example:

your app.config would contain an entry like:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="nameofConnString" connectionString="Data Source=SQLDATA;Initial Catalog=&quot;nameofdatabase&quot;;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password;Connection Timeout=30;Pooling=True; Max Pool Size=200" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

'

Then you could call

conStr = GetConnectionString("nameofConnString")

With Ado.net

You could then establish the connection with:

sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conStr);

sqlConn.Open();

Or with Linq

LinqData ld = new LinqData();
            DataContext dataContext = new DataContext(ld.GetConnectionString(sqlConn));

where LinqData is a class that contains the GetConnectionString() method.